# How to order a json column in postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

So I have a jsonb column with the following structure:

```
{
    "fields": [{
         "name": "John",
         "position": 1
    },{
         "name": "Mike",
         "position": 2
   }]
}
```

The jsonb column is in my "person" table. I would like to select the person table, including the jsonb column, but I also want the jsonb column to be in descending order by "position", is this possible?

So far I have this query.

```
SELECT
    person_id
    name
    jsonb_agg(field ORDER BY field->'fields'->0->>'position' DESC)
FROM
    person
WHERE (
    person_id = 42
) GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table `person` with the following structure and data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (person_id, name, field) AS
VALUES
    (
        42,
        'foo',
        '{
            "fields": [
                { "name": "John", "position": 1 },
                { "name": "Mike", "position": 2 }
            ]
        }'::jsonb
    ),
    (
        13,
        'bar',
        '{
            "fields": [
                { "name": "Anne", "position": 33 },
                { "name": "Melinda", "position": 66 }
            ]
        }'::jsonb
    );
```

First, you'll have to get the array elements as individual rows in order to be able to order them (inner query `data`). Then, you'll have to reconstruct the JSON object:

```sql
SELECT
    person_id,
    name,
    jsonb_build_object(
        'fields',
        jsonb_agg(element ORDER BY element->'position' DESC)
    )
FROM (
    SELECT
        person_id,
        name,
        jsonb_array_elements(field->'fields') AS element
    FROM person
) data
WHERE person_id = 42
GROUP BY
    person_id,
    name;
```

This will yield:

```
 person_id | name |                               jsonb_build_object
-----------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        42 | foo  | {"fields": [{"name": "Mike", "position": 2}, {"name": "John", "position": 1}]}
```

Comment: Thanks man! Saved me couple hours of wondering and no sleep. Lol!